# svcutil failing on IIS7 server, but not on Visual Studio 2010 temporary web server

Tags: web-services, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, silverlight-4.0

I've created a LINQ to SQL class and a Silverlight-enabled WCF Service to a Silverlight 4.0 solution I'm working on. I'm in the process of publishing it to a local IIS7 server, instead of running inside the Visual Studio temporary web server. Whenever I build the project with the service running on the temporary web server, it works fine, but once I move it to my IIS7 web server, it fails with the following errors:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace '' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='SpaceGameDBService']    C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame

Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='SpaceGameDBService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='CustomBinding_SpaceGameDBService']    C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame

Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='CustomBinding_SpaceGameDBService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='SpaceGameDBService']/wsdl:port[@name='CustomBinding_SpaceGameDBService']  C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame

Warning 4   Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 4 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.  C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame

Warning 5   Custom tool warning: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame

Error   6   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'DBServiceReference'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.  C:\Users\MindWorX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MindWorX.Spacegame\MindWorX.Spacegame\Service References\DBServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   MindWorX.Spacegame
```

Now, I believe that warning 4 and 5 and error 6 is a result of warning 1, 2 and 3, so I've ignored them for now. I've been googling around, and seen suggestions telling me to untick the checkbox "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" when I add the service reference to the main Silverlight project, however this hasn't fixed my issue at all. I've tried restarting Visual Studio as well, but this hasn't fixed anything either. I've started to consider that it's some sort of setting in the IIS7 web server, that I'm missing, but I looked around for hours now, and decided to come here for help. I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype), but the "solution" was to not solve the problem, but instead find another way. I'm hoping this time we can find a solution instead.

Comment: I've found a public service that's giving the exact same error as my own service is giving me. I figured this might help anyone reproduce the problem, to easier figure out if they can find a solution. It is located here: http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v3/MerchantService.wsdl

Comment: I've found the shortest possible method of reproducing the problem is by launching the Visual Studio Command Promt, and type in the following command: "svcutil http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v3/MerchantService.wsdl". This seems to indicate it's a problem with either the server, or that svcutil is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I created the solution, I forgot to tick "Enable WCF RIA Services". Along with this I also redid web.config from scratch. How this still works on the development server is a mystery to me, however doing both things solved the problem.