# Custom Tool Warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType

Tags: wcf

I am not sure what this error is.  Thought I would ask you guys on stack overflow what it could be.  I had to change the contract on my service, on a test client that I used, I updated the service reference.  Now I am getting this warning.  How can I resolve this particular issue.

Comment: Can you give the full warning message? Any other warnings around it?

Comment: May be this will hep u  http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/11/25/custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdl-porttype.aspx

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found the answers in [What does this WCF error mean: "Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype) help. In my case, I chose unticking the 'Re-use types' box and that solved it.

**Additional Thoughts: SOA, Distributed Objects, & Coupling**

The ”Service Oriented” Vision implied by a WSDL and the WS-* standards is that the  WSDL itself tells your client *everything you need to know* use the service. On this vision, unticking the 'Re-use types' box is the *correct* approach. You shouldn't be reusing types from anywhere except the wsdl.

Ticking the 're-use types' box is more a "Distributed Objects" approach: your client and service become *coupled* through the types in a shared dll. This is a strong distributed dependency. If the shared objects are updated, the service and all its clients must be updated, *all in sync* with each other. This is one reason why distributed objects fell very much out of favour and SOA took over.

Unless you company chose (possibly accidentally, by sharing libraries on a Nuget feed) a distributed objects architecture, and understand the costs, I would always untick the re-use types.

It reduces coupling.

Comment: This alleviates the symptom and not the cause.  One may want to use the strongly typed class.  This, of course, tightly couples the technologies of the service and client and the service can no longer be used to in part to provide true SOA.  The problem is around the serialisation of various aspects of your models.

Comment: When you're working with a client company's 5 year old code, you can't always change the errant code to solve a problem that isn't the problem you're really trying to solve.
But you're right -- if you needs the types working properly you need to fix them.

Comment: Cheers mate. Been struggling a lot. Simple and perfect answer. Can you explain what happened here?

Comment: Not really. But I guess it's because there are types, in assemblies referenced by your project, that have the same name as types declared in the WCF service contract. My solutions assumes that you _do_ want to use the generated proxy client; This, as @brumScouse points out, is a choice you need to think about.

Comment: Cheers Chris, nice that you agree with me, just like our times at msfg :)

Comment: @brumScouse! I added some thoughts on coupling. What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll I couldn't agree more and articulated better than my original comment.

Comment: @brumScouse! You're too kind :-)

Answer (score 1):

This was the first answer I found when searching for a similar problem, but my issue was a [DataContract] attribute applied to an enum without any [DataMember] attributes, making an empty data contract.

I used this as a resource:

http://www.lukepuplett.com/2010/02/empty-datacontract-causes-misleading.html

It appears as though it is advisable to allow WCF to infer a datacontract for enums.

Answer (score 1):

I find that this also can be solved by using the ?singleWsdl instead of just ?wsdl at the end. There are multiple WSDL files that are linked to, so something too naive to browse them can throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem today when trying to convert and old WSDL to a .cs fike with dotnet-svcutil.

We solved by replacing:

```
<xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType" />
</xsd:complexContent>
```

With

```
<xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="deleteThisField" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexContent>
```

And then manualy delete the *deleteThisField* string in the generated result code.