# Cannot import wsdl:portType, wsdl:binding, wsdl:port

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, proxy, svcutil.exe

I am getting error while generating proxy for WCF using SVCUtil. Error is

```
Attempting to download metadata from 'net.pipe://localhost/WebServices/Mgmt.svc' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO.
Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'SearchCriteria, Service.DataContracts, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
t be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to exclude this type from referenced types.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMgmt']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMgmt']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='NetNamedPipeBinding_IMgmt']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='NetNamedPipeBinding_IMgmt']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='Mgmt']/wsdl:port[@name='NetNamedPipeBinding_I


Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

Everything was working fine till I add a enum member in data contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be, we are reusing `DataContract` while generating proxy & old DataContract dll was not replaced in location from where it is referenced.

Also get help from an response in question [what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype?rq=1)

Answer (score 15):

Other problem could be, not passing all XSDs to svcutil. Our problem was we were using

`svcutil.exe service.wsdl`

instead of

`svcutil.exe service.wsdl first.xsd second.xsd ......`

FYI, we were integrating java web services to our wcf service/.net client.

Comment: Yes that is totally possible. Never thought the aspect of passing xsd since I was using .Net & WCF hierarchical xsd for DataContracts is just compatible as classes for .net POCO classes. +1 for the added scenario.