# Custom tool error: Failed to generate file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a windows application (`C#`) that was created in VS 2012 (`Framework 4.5`) windows forms. The requirements requires it to be used for older versions of windows so I'm setting the target framework to `.NET Framework 4`  and Platform target to `x86`.  Once its done and I try to compile I get the following error:

> Custom tool error: Failed to generate file: The service reference is not valid for the current .NET Framework version or project type. You can change the service reference configuration in the .svcmap

I tried unchecking the box "`Reuse types in referenced assemblies`" in the Service References before flipping to framework 4 but no luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently, sometimes this error can be avoided by simply [re-adding the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883131/590783).  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of re-adding the reference you can also remove the code which is not understood by .NET 4.0 from the `Service References\<reference name>\Reference.svcmap` file. Note that you will need to navigate to this file via explorer, it does not show up in Visual Studio. For my references, I simply removed this line

```
<GenerateTaskBasedAsynchronousMethod>true</GenerateTaskBasedAsynchronousMethod>
```

Then right-click the service reference in VS2013 and hit "Update Service reference". It will rescan the service and generate the Reference.cs file so that it is compatible with .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks, I had the situation where service couldn't be refreshed because it was taken offline by the owner, the only version of service still available was the one that used HTTPS and 2-way SSL handshake (I didn't even try to enable Visual Studio to pull WSDL file from there). So I manually edited the .svcmap but I also had to manually populate Reference.cs because it was truncated (possibly by VS), fortunately we had a project backup so I took Reference.cs from there, I deleted the bin and obj directories, rebuilt all and everything worked again.

Comment: The first thing that I thought was re-adding service reference. I decided to search just because I knew there was a simpler solution. Thanks!